# What does MSL stand for with Rocky Mountain carbon bikes?

Tags: mountain-bike, carbon

I see the carbon fiber bikes from Rocky Mountain bikes use MSL in their branding (up until 2016, at least). What for the letters stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Race Super Light and Marathon Super Light

Comment: Nice find - do you know what these phrases mean?  If so, do please [edit] that extra info into the question.

Comment: Is there a reference available for this too?

Comment: It is mentioned in this pinkbike article: https://www.pinkbike.com/news/2012-Alloy-Rocky-Mountain-Element-First-Look.html

So good enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found some info on [this page](https://www.bikes.com/en/stories/introducing-instinct-msl)

> Named after its instinctive ability to tame a variety of terrain, the Instinct MSL is the perfect platform for epic exploration and now features SMOOTHWALL™ carbon construction (designated as “MSL”)

Seems that MSL is some name that doesn't really stand for anything, but means that it has SMOOTHWALL Carbon construction.

Comment: Good find, but I suspect it has some other meaning.
A bit of googling suggests that RSL models also have the SMOOTHWALL carbon construction